# The smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, programming-challenge, factors

**Problem description:**

2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

**Least Common Multiple(LCM):**

> In arithmetic and number theory, the least common multiple, lowest common multiple, or smallest common multiple of two integers a and b, usually denoted by lcm, is the smallest positive integer that is divisible by both a and b.
>
> *Example:*
>
> LCM(6,7,21)
>
> Multiples of 6: 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60
>
> Multiples of 7: 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 56, 63
>
> Multiples of 21: 21, 42, 63
>
> Find the smallest number that is on all of the lists. We have it in bold above.
>
> So LCM(6, 7, 21) is 42

***The best solution with Euclid GCD algorithm***

**Euclid’s GCD algorithm:**

> *1- The smallest positive number that is evenly divided (divided without remainder) by a > set of numbers is called the Least Common Multiple (LCM).*
>
> *2- All we have to do to solve this problem is find the LCM for the integers {1, 2, 3, 4, > …, 20} using [Euclid’s GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).*
>
> *3- After some reflection you might correctly realize that every integer is divisible by > > 1, so 1 can be removed from the list and use 2 through 20 instead.*
>
> *4- we can eliminate other factors as well.*
>
> *5- We leave 20 in the calculation but then remove its factors {2, 4, 5, 10}. Any number > > evenly divisible by 20 is also evenly divisible by these factors.*
>
> *6- 19 is prime and has no factors— it stays.*
>
> *7- 18 has factors {2, 3, 6, 9} and we already removed 2 but we can remove 3, 6, and 9. 17 > is prime — it stays.*
>
> *8- We continue this numeric carnage until our original list of {1…20} becomes the much > > smaller {11…20}.*
>
> *9- In general, all smaller factors of a bigger number in the list can be safely removed > > without changing the LCM.*

***My Solution***

This is [my solution](https://github.com/AmirMotefaker/ProjectEuler/blob/main/Problem5.py) for [problem 5 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) using Python:

```
 def LCM(a, b):  
    '''Return the least common multiple of
       the specified integer arguments
    '''
    return a // gcd(a, b) * b  
N = int(input("The LCM for numbers 1 through "))
N_reduce = reduce(LCM, range(N//2+1, N+1))
print ("The LCM for numbers 1 through" ,N, "is:", N_reduce)
```

Comment: realize this is an algorithm suggestion and not a code review: to find such a number that is the smallest number divisible by all numbers up to N: you could probably generate all the primes up to N and consider their largest power <= N, and then take that product.

Comment: An implementation of this would look like: numpy.prod([exponentiate_as_much_as_possible(x,n) for x in list_of_primes_up_to(n)] )  where you you need to define the methods list_of_primes_up_to and  exponentiate_as_much_as_possible.

Comment: Python 3.9 [has an `lcm` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm) that takes arbitrarily many arguments.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Just take `20**sum(math.floor(1/math.log(p,20))*math.log(p,20) for p in range(2,21)  if is_prime(p))`.

Comment: ah yea your right the log lets you save a lot of time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight.

If you
- defined "the range-LCM" in a function with a docsting
- presented imports
 and test cases or usage examples,
- added boundary checks (try `N` = 0),
I'd call it great.

You might get a reviewer's extra eye-roll throwing in

```
def largest_power_of_two_not_exceeding(n):
    """ Return the largest power of 2 not exceeding n taken as an integer. """
    n = int(n)
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError
    while 0 != n & n-1:
        n &= n-1
    return n

def LCMup2(n):
    """ return the LCM for numbers 1 through n. """
    n = int(n)
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return reduce(LCM, range((n//6)*2+1, n+1, 2)
                  ) * largest_power_of_two_not_exceeding(n)
```

Comment: See also: https://oeis.org/A003418.